# No visible interface for NSMutableArray declares the selector replaceObjectAtIndex:

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, compiler-errors, nsmutablearray

I have two multidimensional `NSMutableArray`s. Each has four `NSMutableArray`s in the main `NSMutableArray`. I want to exchange one location's data in the 1st array with data from the second, and I'm struggling with the syntax for `replaceObjectatIndex: withObject:`. Here is my line of code:

```
[newStock replaceObjectAtIndex:0 objectAtIndex:0 withObject: [[oldStock objectAtIndex: 0] objectAtIndex: 0]];
```

I'm trying to put the data from the `oldStock` array into the `newStock` array and I'm getting the error message: "No visible @interface for 'NSMutableArray' declares the selector 'replaceObjectAtIndex:'". I have done this with with non-multidimensional arrays so I believe the selector is valid.

Comment: there are tooooo many indices! Is that your actual code in your app?

Comment: yes, that is right from my program. I can't seem to get the right usage or structure for the line.

Comment: well, firstly remove the first `objectAtIndex:0 ` it is completely out of place there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The old syntax in the Objective-C goes like this:

```
[[newStock objectAtIndex:0] replaceObjectAtIndex:0 withObject: [[oldStock objectAtIndex: 0] objectAtIndex: 0]];
```

Fortunately, you can use the new syntax now:

```
newStock[0][0] = oldStock[0][0];
```

Comment: Worked perfectly and I quite like the new syntax! Thanks

Comment: @Keith "new" is not so new anymore, has been here for quite some time already.